# System.AsyncException: System.enqueueJob is not allowed in this context

Tags: exception, queueable-interface

I'm trying to call Queuable interface class from controller class and getting an Exception. Why?

> System.AsyncException: System.enqueueJob is not allowed in this context.

Comment: simplified excerpts of your code may need to be posted; see [ask]

Answer (score 5):

You can't call *any* DML within a "apex:component" when "allowDML" is false (the default value), in any constructor, or in any getter method.

Use an action method if you want to kick off your job on page load:

```
<apex:page controller="XYZ" action="{!startAsync}"> ...
```

If this is inside a component's controller, use allowDML:

```
<apex:component controller="XYZ" allowDML="true"> ...
```

Comment: Well, you can within `<apex:component>`, you just have to set `allowDml="true"`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson That's what I meant to say.

Comment: We'll see if that's actually the cause. Not tagged properly at all so it's hard to tell. Still, good hunch. +1

Comment: For me, this was different as there was a callout happening in the constructor of the controller for a Visualforce page. Moving everything out of the constructor fixed the error - it shouldn't have been there anyway.